# Pass a JS Variable to a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am constructing a Javascript variable in my code after some user interaction. I am trying to send that constructed JS object to another page.

I am trying to send it via HREF using

```
<a href="newpage.html?" + jsvariable">
```

But this one fails. Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

thanks

Comment: You have mismatched quotes

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject variables from javascript like that.

But you may pick up that anchor and manipulate its `href` attribute. There are many ways to do this.

Example:

```
... your html
<a id="someAnchor" href="newpage.html">test</a>

<script>
    document.getElementById("someAnchor").href += "?someParam=" + jsvariable;
</script>
... rest of your html
```

P.S.: Make sure the value of `jsvariable` is url-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the data comes from user input, you'll want to make sure to protect against malicious inputs.

Try something like:

```
var anchorEl = // reference to your anchor.
anchorEl.href += '?data=' + encodeURI(jsvariable)
```

Note, the above solution works in cases where you want further user interaction to get to the next page. If you want to redirect the page directly, you can do:

```
window.location.href = 'newpage.html?data=' + encodeURI(jsvariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think it will work:

1. Convert your object to JSON:

   ```
   var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(jsvariable);
   ```
2. Then pass it into your url:

   ```
   <a href="newpage.html?" + jsonObject>
   ```
3. At your newpage.html, read the URL and extract the information that you need

   ```
   var jsParameter = ...
   ```
4. Convert JSON back to JS object:

   ```
   var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsParameter);
   ```